# Horizontal accordion for images + button for opening EDITED

Tags: jquery, horizontal-accordion

I updated my problem!
So, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kozola/8M6wS/

My code:

```
<style>
#container {
margin-top: 200px;
position: relative; /* needed for absolutely positioning #a and #c */
padding: 0 10px 0 100px; /* will offset for width of #a and #c; and center #b */
border: gray 1px dotted; /* just for the show */
float: left; /* To dynamicaly change width according to children */
height: 100px;
}

#container div { height: 100px; }

#tab1 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
background: gray;
left: 0;
}

#fin {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width:10px;
background: #eee;
right: 0;
}

#content {
white-space: nowrap;
}

#content div { display: inline-block; }
#content img { height: 100px; }

.description { position: absolute; border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; height: 100px; }
</style>



<div id="container">
<div id="tab1">fixed width content</div>
<div id="content">
    <div><a href="#" id="first"><img src="http://goo.gl/FZqqPH" /></a></div>
    <div class="first">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" /><img src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" />    <img src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" />
        <div class="description" style="display: block;">this is a description</div>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#" id="second"><img src="http://goo.gl/FZqqPH" /></a></div>
    <div class="second">
        <img class="second" src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" /><img class="second" src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" /><img class="second" src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" />
        <div class="description" style="display: block;">this is a description</div>        
    </div>
    <div><a href="#" id="third"><img src="http://goo.gl/FZqqPH" /></a></div>
    <div class="third">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" /><img src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" /><img src="http://goo.gl/SIiJfX" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="fin">fin</div>
</div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".first").hide();
$("#first").show();

$("#first").click(function(){
    $(".first").toggle( "slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000 ,function() {
    });

});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".second").hide();
$("#second").show();

$("#second").click(function(){
    $(".second").toggle( "slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000 ,function() {
    });

});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".third").hide();
$("#third").show();

$("#third").click(function(){
    $(".third").toggle( "slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000 ,function() {
    });

});
});

</script>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is: 
1. I need only one tab to be open at a time! So, if I open one tab, others closes. I understand that I could write closing function for every div that is not open at a time, but I will have ~100 divs, so that won't work.
2. I can't figure out why the middle part is not smooth at all! Maybe you guys have some ideas?

Thank you all so much!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Basically, I have tried about ten plugins so I don't have one code to show. I tried making vertical accordion from jqueryUi and than rotating it, but it doesn't really work because the content of each tab are images.

Comment: display: inline-block divs should adapt to content width. You can figure out the rest.

Comment: @Virus721 thank you! That fixed dynamic width div problem!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/uZ3pV/)

```
                $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".title").click(function () {

            $(".content").slideUp("fast");

            $(this).find('.expand').removeClass('collapse');
            if ($(this).next().is(":hidden") == true )
            {
                $('.expand').removeClass('collapse');
                $(this).next().slideDown("normal")
                $(this).find('.expand').addClass('collapse');
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! And maybe you know how to make it horizontal? Rotating doesn't work because content is images!

Comment: I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/kozola/Vxe45/
So, I have figured how to make dynamic width div, but I have a problem with open/close sliding.

Comment: you can find a lot of example in this link http://codepen.io/search/?q=accordion&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false&page=1

Comment: Thank you, but maybe somebody can help me with animate/slide/show jquery? Please please please!

Comment: Yes! Thank you! But when one div is open, others are closed! And they slide out from left to right! I am thinking, maybe Blind effect? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Something like this, only other divs close, when one is open!
http://jsfiddle.net/YBtbk/

Comment: I would like to do this http://jsfiddle.net/wnmUj/2/ ! But make it automatic, so that I don't have to write closing code for every div seperatly!

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't want to sound so demanding!
So the idea is, that I will have ~100 visible divs and every visible div will have several images which will turn visible after I click on the first div